# Change of measure Markov process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let us consider a Markov process in discrete time $X = (X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ which values belong to $\mathbb{R}$ and $X_0 = x$. For each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a probability measure $\mathsf P_x$. When one would like to make $X$ be a martingale, the change of measure can help - namely the process $Z_n \in \mathcal F_n$ such that 
$$
\frac {dQ}{dP}|_{\mathcal F_n} = Z_n
$$ 
and $X$ is a $Q$-martingale. I am a bit confused since for a Markov process there is family of measures $(\mathsf P_x)_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$ rather than a unique one. How one defines a change of measure for a Markov process?

I guess that here $Z_n = f(X_n)$ - but I am looking for the formal definition of change of measure.

Answer (score 5):

One asks that properties (1), (2) and (3) below hold:

(1) The process $(X_n)$ is a $Q$-martingale, that is, $E_Q(X_{n+1}|F_n)=X_n$.

(2) There exists a $P$-martingale $(Z_n)$ such that $E_Q(U)=E(UZ_n)$ for every $F_n$-measurable random variable $U$.

(3) The process $(Z_n)$ is nonnegative.

Condition (1) means that $E_Q(X_{n+1}U)=E_Q(X_nU)$ for every $F_n$-measurable random variable $U$. Condition (2) implies that
$$
E_Q(X_{n+1}U)=E(X_{n+1}UZ_{n+1}),\qquad
E_Q(X_nU)=E(X_nUZ_n).
$$
The two must coincide for every $F_n$-measurable random variable $U$ hence one asks that 
$$
E(X_{n+1}Z_{n+1}|F_n)=X_nZ_n. 
$$
Finally, the goal is to find a nonnegative process $(Z_n)$ such that both $(Z_n)$ and $(X_nZ_n)$ are $(F_n)$-martingales. Such a process is called a **martingale density** for $(X_n)$, see [this paper](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~mschweiz/Files/minimal.pdf) by Martin Schweizer for an introduction in the continuous time setting.

---

Let us now try to exhibit a martingale density for $(X_n)$. For every nonnegative $n$, write $E_n$ for the conditional expectation conditionally on $F_n$ and introduce the processes $(Y_n)$ and $(R_n)$ defined by
$$
Y_{n+1}=X_{n+1}-E_nX_{n+1},\qquad
R_{n+1}=\frac{T_nY_{n+1}}{E_n(X_{n+1}Y_{n+1})}.
$$
for an $F_n$-measurable random variable $T_n$, to be specified later on.

Then $E_nY_{n+1}=0$ and both $T_n$ and the denominator of $R_{n+1}$ are $F_n$-measurable hence $E_nR_{n+1}=0$. Furthermore, $E_n(R_{n+1}X_{n+1})=T_n$.

Finally, a solution to conditions (1)-(2) is given by $Z_0=1$ and, for every positive $n$,
$$
Z_n=\prod_{k=1}^n(1-R_k)\quad\text{with}\ T_n=E_nX_{n+1}-X_n.
$$
An equivalent formula for $R_n$ is
$$
R_{n}=\frac{(X_{n}-E_{n-1}X_{n})(E_{n-1}X_{n}-X_{n-1})}{E_{n-1}(X_{n}^2)-(E_{n-1}X_{n})^2}.
$$
The denominator of $R_n$ is always nonnegative, and one can probably assume it is almost surely positive and that $R_n$ is well defined. But it is not clear (to me) that $R_n\le1$ almost surely, as it should if $Z_n$ is to be a Radon-Nykodym density... In other words I do not know if condition (3) holds for the process $(Z_n)$ defined above (but there might be a simple argument showing either that (3) always holds or, that it may happen that (3) does not hold and that in these cases there is no solution to your problem).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Usually when I am looking for the density process $Z_t$ in a continuous time setting, I solve appropriate SDE to find  a Doléans-Dade exponential which certainly admits (2) and (3) and the only question is to admit (1). Is there a similar approach in the discrete time?